# FlotCharts two colored background

Tags: javascript, html, charts, flot

Using flot chart, I need to split the background into two colors.  It is not going to be right down the middle, it will have a slight offset.

As of what I can see I can not find any documents on the internet that provide this information.  If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.  Can someone put code in on how to do it if it is possible?

Comment: Please ask a question and provide what you have already tried to solve this problem.

Comment: My question is I do not know how to do it and i can not find it... I was thinking of using a bar and changing its opacity, would that work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the easiest way is to use the [grid](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) `markings` option.

For example:

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1 ], {grid: {
    markings: [
        {xaxis: { from: 0, to: 6 },color: "#C11B17"},
        {xaxis: { from: 6, to: 100},color: "#FDD017"}
    ]}
});
```

Produces:

[image]

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CrAFv/1/).

Comment: Is it possible to make a rule that color repeatdly? That is: red for 0-2, 4-6, 8-10...; yellow for 2-4, 6-8, 10-12...

Comment: Thanks, @Mark, I was thinking about something more intuitive, but I guess Flot is not that powerful.